# How to solve - A Merge Field with the tag "" already exists for this list - Mailchimp?

Tags: mailchimp

I've Audience created in Mailchimp with only three merge fields namely First Name, Email and Phone. Now I want to add a new merge field but whenever I click on add new field it shows this specific error.
"A Merge Field with the tag "" already exists for this list."

I searched almost every forums but can't find any solution. I'm new to mailchimp.